# Banach subalgebra generated by commutative set equals the centralizer of its centralizer

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, banach-algebras

Let $A$ be a unital Banach algebra and $S\subset A$ a subset consisting of commuting elements. Let $C(S)$ be the centralizer of $S$, that is, $y \in C(S)$ iff $ys=sy$ for all $s \in S$. I have already proved that $C(C(S))$ is a commutative Banach subalgebra and I want to prove that $C(C(S))$  is actually the smallest Banach subalgebra containing $S$. Let's denote by $M$ such smallest subalgebra.
Now, if $\langle D \rangle$ denotes the subspace generated by a set $D$ then it's clear that if $B$ is any subalgebra containing $S$ then $E:=\langle s_1 s_2 \ldots s_n : s_i \in S \textrm{ and } n \in \mathbb{N} \rangle \subset B$ and therefore $\overline{E} \subset B$. Since $\overline{E}$ is clearly a subalgebra it follows that $M=\overline{E}$ so I just have to prove that $C(C(S))=\overline{E}$.

In order to do this, I thought the following: we have that $E \subset C(S)$ and thus, since $C(S)$ is a closed subset it follows that $\overline{E} \subset C(S)$. This last contention entails that $C(C(S))\subset C(\overline{E})$. Hence, if I could prove that $C(\overline{E})=\overline{E}$ it'd be done. However, I am not sure this last claim it's true. Actually, it doesn't seem true and therefore I'm probably following the wrong path.

Any hint in order to prove this statement?

In advance thank you.

Comment: This is quite false as stated. For example, if $A$ is commutative then the centralizer of every subset is all of $A$. You need more hypotheses on either $A$ or $S$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Hmmmm seems you're right. What if I assume that $A$ is non-commutative? Honestly, I doesn't occur to me a reasonable hypothesis on $A$ or $S$.

Comment: That doesn't really help, we can just take $A$ to be the direct product of some large commutative Banach algebra and $M_2(\mathbb{C})$, say. I don't have a counterexample if $A = M_n(\mathbb{C})$, though (I don't think it's true either, I just don't have a counterexample). Where did this problem come from?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan you're right, the result it's not true even if $A$ is non-commutative. Actually, if we take $A=M_2(\mathbb{C})$ as you said we can find $S$ such that $C(C(S)) \neq M$, where $M$ is the smallest closed subalgebra containing $S$ (according to me, we can take $S$ as the singleton consisting of one convenient matrix of the canonical basis).This problem is from the book "An introduction from operator algebras" by Kehe Zhu, chapater 5, page 33.